# Openfire + Spark: can audiocall contact but cannot audiocall in group

Tags: apache-spark, openfire

I'm using Openfire with Candy, and I got 2 clients with Spark (one in Ubuntu 14.04, other in OSX 10.10), both with jitsi-jingle, without original jingle.

I can make an audiocall from user1 to user2 and vice-versa, but cannot make an audiocall in a conference.

error.log doesn't return me anything.

What can be happening?